# Doctor and EVA specialist -- good idea?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, mission-design

The book "The Martian" describes a six-people manned mission to Mars. One of the astronauts is both the ship's primary medical doctor/surgeon and primary extravehicular activity specialist. Is such a job division rational? Would you find it reasonable to have in a similar mission?

It seems to me that EVA is one of the most dangerous activities occurring on a spacecraft, so I would try to keep the two roles separate so that the surgeon is available to take care of an injured EVA astronaut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every crew member is instructed in first aid. Watney showed us crew members know the basics of surgery. The sort of injury likely to be experienced during EVA is the kind that likely least requires thorough medical expertise. The main medical doctor's duties are probably more subtle, long-term afflictions that one does need thorough experience for.